# How to get Number of files touched, Number of lines added, Number of lines removed from for commit in repo.iter_commits(branch) using python git?

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, gitpython

I would like to store the following info per commit like so,

```
for commit in repo.iter_commits(branch):
    author_name=commit.author.name
    commit_id=commit
    commit_authored_date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(commit.authored_date)
    commit_committed_date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(commit.committed_date)
    num_files_touched=?
    num_lines_added=?
    num_lines_removed=?
```

how can I do this?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @RomainValeri I have commit id, author name, and commit date so far.

Comment: You added the python-2.7 tag. Do you really need a solution in Python 2.7, or would a more recent version of Python do instead?

Comment: @joanis I would prefer python 2.7, but a solution otherwise would still be helpful If you have one.

Comment: No, I don't have a solution, but it's a surprising tag to see in 2022, so I wanted to confirm you really meant it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for commit in repo.iter_commits(branch):
        author_name=commit.author.name
        commit_id=commit
        commit_authored_date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(commit.authored_date)
        commit_committed_date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(commit.committed_date)
        num_files_touched=commit.stats.total['files']
        num_lines_added=commit.stats.total['insertions']
        num_lines_removed=commit.stats.total['deletions']
```

This fetches the number of files touched, the number of lines added, and number of lines removed for each commit